# Error: java.sql.SQLDataException,Invalid character string format for type int. I really don't understand?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a problem with my project. When i browse `http://localhost:8080/user/form` to fill information user

[image]

Then submit form to save user and automaticlly direct `http://localhost:8080/user/list` to display list User, but occur following error:

> Hibernate: insert into userdat (age, birthday, gender, password,
>   username) value s (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) Mar 27, 2016 8:30:17 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$Standar
>   dWarningHandler logWarning WARN: SQL Warning Code: 10000, SQLState:
>   01J01 Mar 27, 2016 8:30:17 AM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$Standar
>   dWarningHandler logWarning WARN: Database 'D:\PROJECTSPRING\userdb'
>   not created, connection made to existin g database instead. Mar 27,
>   2016 8:30:17 AM
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiat or
>   initiateService INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   Hibernate: select user0_.username as username1_0_, user0_.age as
>   age2_0_, user0_ .birthday as birthday3_0_, user0_.gender as
>   gender4_0_, user0_.password as passw ord5_0_ from userdat user0_ Mar
>   27, 2016 8:30:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
>   logExce ptions WARN: SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: 22018 Mar 27, 2016
>   8:30:17 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExce
>   ptions ERROR: Invalid character string format for type int. [WARNING]
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute que ry
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute
>   query
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQL
>   ExceptionTypeDelegate.java:52)
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.conver
>   t(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlException
>   Helper.java:111)
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: Invalid character string format
>   for type i nt.
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknow
>   n Source)
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source
>   )
>           at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException
>   (Unknown Source)

**Here file UserDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.getObject().openSession();
        session.save(user);
        session.flush();
        session.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.getObject().openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
        return (List<User>)query.list();
    }
```

**Here file User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userdat",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="username")})
public class User {
    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }
    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }
    @Column(name = "birthday", nullable = false)
    public Date getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(Date birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }
    @Column(name="age", nullable = false)
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    private Date birthDay;
    private Integer age;
    private Gender gender;


}
```

Here file Gender.java

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE("Male"),
    FEMALE("Female"),
    OTHER("Other");
    private String name;

    private Gender(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender(){
        return this.name;
    }
        }
```

**Here Create Table in DB**

```
public void createTable() throws SQLException{
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:D:/PROJECTSPRING/dbuser;create=true");
            createTableNotExist(connection,"userdat", "create table userdat"
                    + "(username varchar(1000) primary key,"
                    + "password varchar(1000),birthday date,"
                    + "age integer,gender varchar(100))");
//          createTableNotExist(connection,"subject","create table subject"
//                  + "(id bigint primary key generated always as identity(start with 1,increment by 1),"
//                  + "title varchar(1000),student integer,score integer)" );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Try using `Embeddable` annotation on `Gender` class and with `Embedded` annotation on `Gender` field in `User` class. Refer to [link](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-component-using-annotations-1.html) to see the usage.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, i have try with your way, however when i `mvn jetty:run` to run server but  occur error:

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not au
towire field: private edu.java.spring.service.user.dao.UserDao edu.java.spring.s
ervice.user.controller.UserRestServiceController.userDao; nested exception is or
g.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
name 'userDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception

Comment: is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire
field: public org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean edu.jav
a.spring.service.user.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is o
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
 name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/userservice-
servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernat
e.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tupl
e.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, you have another way ????

Comment: Not sure if the error `Invalid character string format for type int` got resolved. Regarding `BeanCreationException` can you post the complete exception along with spring configuration file. Also do you have all the spring beans configured correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Enums persist by ordinal number if they do not annotated with `@Enumerated`. In this case  hibernate expects int but gets varchar(100). Code below solves the problem.

```
@Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is saying that it wants to store `Gender` as in Integer since it is an enum type. Change the database creation to:

gender integer

Answer (score 0):

I'm publishing this answer because this error can be also caused by using column names in the CSV file.

Here is the thing: I extracted some data from a DB in CSV format using an automation tool. Then I tried to import data to Apache Derby without any success. 
After a couple of hours finally I figured out that column names should have been removed from the file.

It's a very simple solution but sometimes we just want run into the process ASAP and forget the details about process configuration.

I hope this post help others.

Cheers!